# Error connecting to SQL Server Database using yaml parameters in python/pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Not able to connect to SQL Server using Drivers while calling YAML parameters w.r.t SQL Server Database.

**test.yaml** file:

```yaml
#parameters
hostname : "server_name_XX"
database_name: "DB"
username: "ABC"
password: "XXX"
conn_str: "driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', host=hostname, database=database_name, user=username, password=password"
table: "test_table"
```

The above test.yaml paramters are called in the below python script:
**extract.py**

```py
def extract(params):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(params['conn_str'])
    src_cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = f"SELECT * FROM {params['table']}"
    src_cursor.execute(query)
```

Error:

> InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
> Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0)
> (SQLDriverConnect)')

Same is connecting from command prompt though.

Comment: I think you need to use semicolons instead of commas to delimit the parameters of the connection string: `conn_str: "driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'; host=hostname;database=database_name;user=username;password=password"`

Comment: Tried that one too earlier, same error

Comment: Try removing the quotes from the driver value. I think that might be tripping up the client. `conn_str: "driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; host=hostname;database=database_name;user=username;password=password"`

Comment: So what are the connection string keywords `host`, `user` and `password`? Did you see those in a reference page somewhere or have you used them with other database drivers and assumed they'd just work with ODBC Driver for SQL Server? Have you read the [Supported DSN/Connection String Keywords and Connection Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute#supported-dsnconnection-string-keywords-and-connection-attributes) documentation yet?

Comment: I changed as mentiond in the document
conn_str: "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; Server=hostname;Database=database_name;UID=username;PWD=passwords" 
getting error:
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); 
[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.